# Cross platform scheme for sttoping background services

Tags: algorithm, service, architecture

I'm working on a little tool like NGINX which I want to run in background as a service. I would like to offer to the user a few commands like:

- `start`: starts the tool and make it run in background.
- `stop`: stops the service.

How could I manage the sttoping action? I thought in two possible solutions:

1. Run as process in background and when the user run `stop` command it kills the process with its id.
2. Run as process in background listening on a specific port. When the user run `stop` command it send a message to that port with the signal to stop the service.

Which one will be more robust and why? Is there any other better method? **I'm looking for a cross platform solution**.

I think that the most convenient solution is the second one as a listening port is more cross platform that a daemon which is only a valid concept in Linux or a service in Windows. Also, you could expand the functionality of the service sending commands to the listening server to retrieve its information, stats or reload tool's settings.

Any kind of help would be very appreciated